# Postgres/Postgis : setting up rls policies

Tags: postgresql, policy-based-management

So i'm trying to configure the different accesses for mutliple users to my postgres/postgis database.

Basically I have 1 manager user and 4 weak users accessing the db.

What I would like to do is to prevent a weak user to be able to delete entries that have been made by an another user in the database. BUT all users should still be able to see all entries from all users in the db.

So i'm wondering what combination of permissive and restrictive rls policies i should set up to make it work?

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: The passwd file example in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-rowsecurity.html) can be adapted for this. You will have to store the creating username in the row in order to know who "owns" it. Is that something you can do, or is other users knowing the row "owner" a problem?

Answer (score 1):

That should be simple. Create a column that contains the name of the user that added the row and hide it behind a view.

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   data text,
   creator name DEFAULT current_user NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW tab_v AS SELECT id, data FROM tab;

GRANT SELECT, DELETE ON tab_v TO users, admin;
```

Use only `tab_v` in your application; the users don't have access to `tab`. Rows inserted into `tab_v` will end up in `tab` with the correct `creator` set.

Then create the appropriate policies:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

-- everybody can SELECT and INSERT everything
CREATE POLICY tab_read ON tab FOR SELECT TO PUBLIC
   USING (TRUE);
CREATE POLICY tab_insert ON tab FOR INSERT TO PUBLIC
   WITH CHECK (TRUE);

-- normal users can delete their own rows
CREATE POLICY user_delete ON tab FOR DELETE TO users
   USING (creator = current_user);

-- admin can delete everything
CREATE POLICY admin_delete ON tab FOR DELETE TO admin
   USING (TRUE);
```